# Synchronising Linux host to NTP Server

Tags: linux, command-line, date-time, ntp

I'm trying to synchronize the time of Linux host with NTP server. The configuration file is modified with server information and the NTP service is started using the command

service ntpd start

By executing the following command i have checked whether the NTP server is added or not

ntpq -pn

The name of the ntp server is been listed in the output.

But there is no change in time. Help me to synchronize the time with NTP server permanently (without ntpdate command as time is changed when reboot occurs)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually `ntpdate` has to be used before syncing and run at boot time

Comment: I have tried the same by executing ntpdate command and then ntpd. The clock changes but the synchronisation symbol * is not displayed for the ntp server when i execute ntpq -pn command

Comment: could you post the output from `ntpq -pcrv` please in your question which you can edit with the link underneath.

Answer (score 1):

For several reasons, `ntpd` does not like to correct large time discrepancies in a single  swoop. What it does instead is to `slew` the clock gently, but this in turn means that it will catch up very slowly.

In fact, [the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpd) states:

> **-x**
>
> Normally, the time is slewed if the offset is less than the step
>   threshold, which is 128 ms by default, and stepped if above the
>   threshold. This option sets the threshold to 600 s, which is well
>   within the accuracy window to set the clock manually. Note: Since the
>   slew rate of typical Unix kernels is limited to 0.5 ms/s, each second
>   of adjustment requires an amortization interval of 2000 s. Thus, an
>   adjustment as much as 600 s will take almost 14 days to complete....

My suggestion is that you synchronize the clock manually with `date`, as follows,

```
date -s "7/27/2016 07:07:00"
```

and then check whether `ntpd` is able to bring, slowly, the discrepancy down to just about zero.

Comment: Other than that i have used ntpdate command and then i have started the ntpd service..

Comment: But stil the symbol * is not shown on the server when i execute ntpq -pn command